# Returning object inside array with closest date to NOW

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdate

I have an array with objects, each object holds a property called "date" i wanna go trough that array and find the object that has the closest date to current date.

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface FixturesObject : NSObject
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *homeGoals;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *awayGoals;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *homeName;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *awayName;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *round;
@property (strong, nonatomic) UIImage *homeLogo;
@property (strong, nonatomic) UIImage *awayLogo;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *date;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSDate *date2;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSNumber *epoch;


+(FixturesObject *)fixtureFromXMLDictionary: (NSDictionary *)dict;

@end

#import "FixturesObject.h"

@implementation FixturesObject
@synthesize homeGoals, awayGoals, homeLogo, awayLogo, homeName, awayName, round, date, epoch, date2;


+(FixturesObject *)fixtureFromXMLDictionary:(NSDictionary *)dict{

    FixturesObject *object =[[FixturesObject alloc]init];

    object.homeGoals = dict[@"HomeGoals"];
    object.awayGoals = dict[@"AwayGoals"];
    object.homeName = dict[@"HomeTeam"];
    object.awayName = dict[@"AwayTeam"];
    object.homeLogo = [UIImage imageNamed:dict[@"HomeTeam_Id"]];;
    object.awayLogo = [UIImage imageNamed:dict[@"AwayTeam_Id"]];
    object.round = dict[@"Round"];
    object.date = dict[@"Date"];

    NSString * dateString = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%@",object.date];
    NSDateFormatter* dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ"];
    NSDate* myDate = [dateFormatter dateFromString:dateString];

    object.date2 = myDate;
    return object;

}

@end
```

mainview.m

```
FixturesObject *closestObject;
NSTimeInterval closestInterval = DBL_MAX;

for (FixturesObject *myObject in newFixtureObjectArray) {
    NSTimeInterval interval = ABS([myObject.date2 timeIntervalSinceDate:[NSDate date]]);
    if (interval < closestInterval) {
        closestInterval = interval;
        closestObject = myObject;
                NSLog(@"My closest date: %@", myObject);
    }
}
```

Updated as requested, thank you guys so much for your help!

Comment: Can we see the public interface for `FixturesObject` because it appears that `myObject.date` is an instance of `NSString`?

Comment: it is an instance of NSString

Comment: i created a second property with NSDate the error went away but now it just crashes with this error:

-[NSNull date2]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x102f20b50 @ this line :         if (interval < closestInterval) {

Comment: I suggest putting a break point in the loop and making sure that date2 is an object of class NSDate.

Comment: i found that the issue is that my main array, which is mutable, i inserted 2 null objects at index 0 and 1, and they must remain there, otherwise it breaks my app design, so... how do i  add a null object at index 0 and 1 for a nsarray? :P

Comment: You keep moving to different problems with your code without adequately describing them. The only way to put null objects into an array is to use NSNull. Then you have to write special-case code that detects the NSNulls and skips them. IF you pass an NSNull as a parameter to a method like `timeIntervalSinceDate`, you will crash just like you reported. I would suggest finding a different solution than putting null objects in your array.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure that myObject.date is an object of class NSDate. It won't work if it is an other type of object. Nor will it work correctly if myObject.date is nil.

The new error you are reporting (`[NSNull date2]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x102f20b50`) does not make sense for the line you are reporting it on. There must be something else going on.

Can you update your original question with your new code, and also show the header for your `myObject` class?

Answer (score 0):

I think you're going to do better to sort the array using `sortedArrayUsingComparator`.

```
    NSDate *currentDate = [NSDate date];

    NSArray *sortedFixtureObjectArray = [newFixtureObjectArray sortedArrayUsingComparator:^NSComparisonResult(id obj1, id obj2) {

        if (![obj1 isKindOfClass:[FixturesObject class]])
             return NSOrderedDescending;
        else if (![obj2 isKindOfClass:[FixturesObject class]])
            return NSOrderedAscending;

        FixturesObject *one = (FixturesObject *)obj1;
        FixturesObject *two = (FixturesObject *)obj2;

        double firstInterval = [one.date2 timeIntervalSinceDate:currentDate];
        double secondInterval = [two.date2 timeIntervalSinceDate:currentDate];

        firstInterval = (firstInterval < 0 ? -1 * firstInterval : firstInterval);
        secondInterval = (secondInterval < 0 ? -1 * secondInterval: secondInterval);

        if (firstInterval < secondInterval)
            return NSOrderedAscending;
        else if (firstInterval > secondInterval)
            return NSOrderedDescending;

        return NSOrderedSame;

    }];
```

This will generate a sorted array where the 0th item is the one with the time interval nearest to the current date.

You'll notice that I declared `currentDate` outside of the block.  This way you will be comparing all the dates with the same date rather than a new date every time.

Comment: -[NSNull date2]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x102f1fb50, my array. my first array has index 0 and index 1 has Null, how can i add the same for this new one? inserobjectatindex is only for mutable arrays

Comment: You can check to see if the object is of type NSNull with [object isKindOfClass:[NSNull class]] .  If that object is object 1, return NSOrderedDescending, otherwise NSOrderedAscending.

Comment: Better yet, check to be sure they're both FixturesObjects.